# Julia Pkg.add inCLI vs Jupyter

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook

Is there any difference if I do Pkg.add("Interact") in the cli window vs in a Jupyter notebook?   How much of the cli namespace is available in the notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. The packages are added to the same directory and available in the REPL, in the Juno IDE, in IJulia, in VSCode, etc.